# Replace value in html table Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I'm writing a script which displays the last 7 backups of my server. The scripts outputs the following: TimeCreated, Level, ID, Message,Size in a html table.

my script:

```
$lastsevendays = (get-date) - (new-timespan -day 7)
$MyObject = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName='Microsoft-Windows-Backup'; StartTime=$lastsevendays}
$BackupSize = @{ Name = "BackupSize"; Expression = { (($objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\LaBackup").Size) / 1MB) } }


$MyObject |
        Select 'TimeCreated', 'LevelDisplayName','ID', 'Message', $BackupSize |
        ConvertTo-HTML -Head $Header |
        Out-file C:\Users\script.htm
```

I want the script to run everyday and automatically remove backups row which date back from more than 7 seven.

I think i'm supposed to select row which have "Date" less or equal than seven days ago,
and delete them to add more recent row.

I have no idea how i could do this as, ConvertTo-HTML seems to regenerate a whole table each time it's called.

Some ideas??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-Backup | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.TimeCreated -gt [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-7); }
```

This uses the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter events that are older than 7 days in the `Microsoft-Windows-Backup` log.

### EDIT

I guess I misunderstood what you were looking for. All I did was change the `-lt` operator to `-gt`.

Comment: Thanks, but it goes from 03/21/2014 to 08/03/2012. I just need to get the last 7 days that is to say from 03/29/2014 to 03/22/2014 and so on... I want the oldest row to be replaced with a new one